# How do I change the name of a custom policy in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I want to use multiple base policies, so how do I upload a new base policy with a different name without overriding the old one?

Answer (score 2):

You can’t change the prefix (B2C_1A), but to change the “TrustFrameworkBase” part of it, update the attribute below (should be at the top of the policy file)

```
PolicyId="B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase"
```

Comment: [Uservoice idea](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/33150217-remove-b2c-1a-prefix) to remove this restriction